# Windowing Strategy for Unbounded Side Input

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a pipeline which streams IoT log data. In addition, it has a bounded side input, containing the initial configurations of the devices. This configuration changes over time and has to be updated by specific logs (ConfigLogs) coming from the main PubSub source. All remaining logs (PayloadLogs) need to consume at some point the updated configuration.

In order to have access to the latest configuration, I came up with the following pipeline design:

[image]

However, I was unable to get this to work. In particular, I struggle with the correct window/trigger strategy for the side input of `Use Config Side Input`.

Here is a pseudocode example

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.transforms import window
from apache_beam.transforms.trigger import AccumulationMode, Repeatedly, AfterCount


class UpdateConfig(beam.DoFn):
    # currently dummy logic
    def process(self, element, outdated_config_list):
        outdated_config = outdated_config_list[0]
        print(element)
        print(outdated_config)
        yield {**outdated_config, **{element[0]: element[1]}}


class UseConfig(beam.DoFn):
    # currently dummy logic
    def process(self, element, latest_config_list):
        print(element)
        print(latest_config_list)


with beam.Pipeline() as pipeline:
        # Bounded Side Input
        outdated_config = (
            pipeline
            | "Config BQ" >> beam.Create([{3: 'config3', 4: 'config4', 5: 'config5'}])
            | "Window Side Input" >> beam.WindowInto(window.GlobalWindows())
        )

        # Unbounded Source
        config_logs, payload_logs = (
            pipeline
            | "IoT Data" >>
            beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription="MySub").with_output_types(bytes)
            | "Decode" >> beam.Map(lambda x: eval(x.decode('utf-8')))
            | "Partition Config/Payload Logs" >>
            beam.Partition(lambda x, nums: 0 if type(x[0]) == int else 1, 2)
        )

        # Update of Bounded Side Input with part of Unbounded Source
        latest_config = (
            config_logs
            | "Update Batch Config" >>
            beam.ParDo(UpdateConfig(), batch_lookup_list=beam.pvalue.AsList(outdated_config))
            | "LatestConfig Window/Trigger" >>
            beam.WindowInto(
                window.GlobalWindows(),
                trigger=Repeatedly(AfterCount(1)),
                accumulation_mode=AccumulationMode.DISCARDING
            )
        )

        # Use Updated Side Input
        (
            payload_logs
            | "Use Config Side Input" >>
            beam.ParDo(UseConfig(), latest_config_list=beam.pvalue.AsList(latest_config))
        )
```

which I feed with the following type of dummy data

```
# ConfigLog: (1, 'config1')
# PayloadLog: ('1', 'value1')
```

The prints of `Update Batch Config` are always executed, however Dataflow waits indefinitely in `Use Config Side Input`, even though I added an `AfterCount` trigger in `LatestConfig Window/Trigger`.

When I switch to a `FixedWindow` (and also add one for the `PayloadLogs`), I do get the prints in `Use Config Side Input`, but the side input is mostly empty, since the `FixedWindow` is triggered after a fixed amount of time, irrespectively if I had an incoming `ConfigLog` or not.

What is the correct windowing/triggering strategy when using a unbounded side input?

Comment: Hi @CaptainNabla, Does this [document](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#windowing) help?

Comment: Thanks! I am aware of the programming guide, however, it could not help me with my issue.

Comment: @CaptainNabla Were you able to figure this out? I'm running into a similar issue.

Comment: Unfortunately not